# MySQL Insert & Joins

Tags: mysql, join, insert

i saw this

> In MySQL, joins work for INSERT,
>   UPDATE, and DELETE statements. It's
>   possible to change data in more than
>   one table when joining tables in an
>   UPDATE or DELETE statement.

in an answer for a question from the mysql certification guide. is it true? inserts with joins? an example of it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can INSERT ... SELECT with mysql, which is probably what they mean. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tableNew (col1, col2)
  SELECT tbl1.col1, tbl2.col2
  FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2
```

Comment: Consider using REPLACE instead of INSERT, it updates duplicates OR inserts missing values

Comment: @Marius, What about inserting into the joined table (the two tables) like we can with `delete`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3860308/632951

Answer (score 12):

To complete the set, here's one for DELETE. This is a common method for deleting rows together with their dependencies without triggers.

```
DELETE users, comments
FROM users JOIN comments ON comments.author=users.id
WHERE users.isspammer=1
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this for Update statement like this,

```
Update C
Join tableB B on B.id=C.bid
Join tableA A on A.id=B.aid
Set C.status='Active',
A.status='Active'
Where A.id=1 or A.id=2 or A.id=3
```

check this for your reference.

http://www.siusic.com/wphchen/mysql-update-statement-159.html

http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php