# Multiple unique entries on table update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, unique

Right now I have a table with an auto increment id number, a name, and a definition
I am updating the table with values from another table using

```
INSERT INTO words(id, word, definition) SELECT id, word, definition FROM temp 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE words.word = temp.word, words.definition=temp.definition;
```

The table temp has the same exact column layout as the table I am using, and it works fine except when I delete an entry from the middle of temp and then update my main table.
For example,

```
temp
id  word definition
1   bob   is a cat
2   sam   is a dog
3   doug  is a monk
4   croe  is a bird
```

table main is set to that
Then I remove row 2 from temp

```
temp
    id  word definition
    1   bob   is a cat
    2   doug  is a monk
    3   croe  is a bird
```

and then update main table

```
main
id  word definition
1   bob   is a cat
2   sam   is a dog
3   croe  is a bird
4   croe  is a bird
```

because temp only has 3 rows now, but main HAD 4, the 4th row isn't deleted. I tried to fix this by making word a unique column, and now I get the error that there is a duplicate entry for key 'word'.
So how do I fix this?

Comment: You forgot to add a unique index on main.word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html),

> In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

so, what you could do is make `word` your primary key, and get rid of the `id` column. That should do the trick :)

Your query then becomes

```
INSERT INTO words(word, definition) SELECT word, definition FROM temp 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE words.word = temp.word, words.definition=temp.definition;
```

If you need arbitrary sorting, I would create an additional table

```
CREATE TABLE word_order (VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY, sort_order INT)
```

and then when you run your queries

```
SELECT words.word,
       words.definition
FROM words
JOIN word_order
ON words.word = word_order.word
ORDER BY word_order.sort_order
```

Your `INSERTS` become a little more complicated though, you'd have to run multiple inserts. See [sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query).

Also, this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/453077/Generating-Keys-for-a-Custom-Sort-Order) has some more ideas on the topic.

Comment: It works now, but it is automatically ordering the table based on the primary key. Do you know how to make it unordered?

Comment: So, you're asking if you can use this technique and still order the words however you want?

Comment: Yeah, the words weren't originally organized, but when I made word the primary key, they became sorted alphabetically. so yes

Comment: Edited with some ideas on arbitrary sorting.