# How to insert data in different tables using MySql database?

Tags: mysql, database, insert

Normally I insert data in MySql in one table (sales) example.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO sales (price, user, date) " +
                             "VALUES(" +
                             "'" + txtQuant.Text + "'," +
                             "'" + txtLog.Text + "'," +
                              "NOW())";
```

But now I change my mind and decided to separately create another table which will I name settings for column price. this is my first time to do this so I have no idea what to do.

I tried this.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO sales (user, date), settings (price) " +
                             "VALUES(" +
                             "'" + txtLog.Text + "'," +
                              "NOW())", "'" + txtQuant.Text + "'";
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not use two querys ?

Comment: @Jayseer If you separate the statements with a semi-colon, you can execute them as "one query".

Code:
`INSERT INTO tbl(field, field) VALUES(val, val); INSERT INTO tbl2(field2, field2) VALUES(val2, val2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do it with 2 queries

```
INSERT INTO sales (user, date) values('user', now()); 
INSERT INTO settings (price) values(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support inserting into multiple tables in a single query (see [sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)).

You can place multiple queries in a single transaction to ensure that they are either both successful or neither. The above question has an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with one query as INSERT can only insert data to one table in mysql. You can either

- write this as two queries and execute them as a batch
- create a stored procedure that would execute two insert command

You can wrap those inserts in transaction if you need to make sure that both queries will write the data

use those queries

```
$query1 ="INSERT INTO sales (user, date) values(.....)"; 
$query2 ="INSERT INTO settings (price) values(......)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the two queries:

```
INSERT INTO sales (user, date) VALUES ( ... )
```

Followed by

```
INSERT INTO settings (price) VALUES ( ... )
```

If `sales` has an `auto_increment` primary key, you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the second query to reference `sales.id` after the insertion.

```
INSERT INTO settings (sale_id, price) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ... )
```

Note that correlated queries like these are best put inside a transaction.