# Inserting data in 2 table on the same form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have a table `file`, this table will keet PDF files

`file`(`id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`)

and a table `studentForm`, only texts will be kept here

`studentForm`(`firstName`, `name`, `emailAddress`, `fieldStudy`, `university`, `semester`, `linkedin`, `number`)

My insert in PHP is inserting only into `studentForm` table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO studentForm (
            firstName,
            name,
            emailAddress,
            fieldStudy,
            university,
            semester,
            linkedin,
            number
       )
        VALUES (
             '$firstName',
             '$name',
             '$emailAddress',
             '$fieldStudy',
             '$university',
             '$semester',
             '$linkedin',
             '$number'               
        )";
```

I would like to insert data also into the `file` table. How can I do this JOIN table in a simple way?

Comment: Couldn't you just use two insert statements? That seems easier to understand what is going on rather than combining the two.

Comment: `INSERT INTO studentForm` is one query, you need to execute the other one too

Comment: You need to use 2 queries. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query

Comment: maybe following link will answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time

Comment: what is name ? if these tables are to be linked steer toward id's (like int, not name)