# How to insert different values into two tables with single submit and inner join in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

is it possible to insert Values into two tables using inner join..?
tables are user,details

user table contains
user_id,name,passwrd

details table contain
id,address,email

what i Did:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])=='SUBMIT')
  {

       $user_name        =   $_POST['user_name'];
       $user_password    =   $_POST['user_password'];

       $details_email   =   $_POST['details_email']; 
       $details_phn      =   $_POST['details_phn'];
       $details_age     =   $_POST['details_age'];

 $SQL_QUERY="INSERT INTO tbl_user(user_name,user_password)VALUES('$user_name','$user_password')";
 $result=mysql_query($SQL_QUERY);

   $SQL_QUERY1="INSERT INTO tbl_details(details_email,details_phn,details_age)VALUES('$details_email','$details_phn','$details_age')";
 $result1=mysql_query($SQL_QUERY1);

   }
```

how can i rewrite with innerjoin...pls someone help me..

Comment: No. It isn't. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

> MySQL supports the following JOIN syntaxes for the table_references
>   part of SELECT statements and multiple-table DELETE and UPDATE
>   statements:

You can't use `join` for `INSERT`.
Sorry.

May I ask , what's the problem with 2 queries?

**UPDATE**
Check @VolkerK 's comment,
It offers alternative possible solutions:
[sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: Its working...But i just wanted to know that is it possible to use inner  join..thats all...

Comment: So I'm sorry , it's impossible.