# Is it possible to insert data in two different table using single mysql query without transaction?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is possible using transaction but I want to do it using single mysql query.

this is which common format transaction

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

but I need to know a single mysql query is possible?

Comment: Do you really need to do this in a single query, or in a single transaction?

Comment: It can't be done in one query in MySql. Just use `start transaction` then two `inserts` and `commit` at the end if you are using InnoDb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can not do this in MySQL. But you can do this using concat query.

```
INSERT INTO your_table
(value1,value2,value3)
  VALUES
(a,b,c),
(d,e,f),
(i,j,k);
```

But this is not your question answer. so Your question answer is NO. MYSQL is not support it still now.

Comment: Yes your answer perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be done in single statement like

```
insert into table1,table2
```

either you do separately like

```
insert into table1 ...

insert into table2 ...
```

(OR)

Wrap the insert statements in stored procedure and call that procedure like

```
create procedure sp_insert_multiple
as
begin
    insert into table1 ...

    insert into table2 ...
end
```

Call the SP

```
exec sp_insert_multiple
```

Comment: Not two query , only one insert query

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam, you can't insert values to multiple table in single insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it is not possible to insert multiple table in single query. you can  insert multiple row in a single table .   like as

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test
(a1,a2,a3)
VALUES
(1,2,3),
(4,5,6),
(7,8,9);
```

you can do this in Oracle

by using procedure you can insert

```
create procedure insert_query
as
begin
insert into tbl_test1(a1,a2,a3) VALUES (1,2,3)
insert into tbl_test2 (b1,b2,b3) VALUES (1,2,3)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. However, you can use a transaction and have both of them be contained within one transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES ('1','2','3');
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES ('one','two','three');
COMMIT;
```

[See the following rule](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Answer (score -2):

you can do that like coz

MySQL doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(...)
INSERT INTO PHONES VALUES(...)
```

here is a link of detail answer..

[sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: @Haaron, but this answer says `you can't do it in MySql, but you can do it in Oracle`. Sure, in Oracle it's possible, but the question is about MySql.

Comment: Kodirko yes thats true you cant do that in mySQL.

Comment: Not two insert query, only one insert query

Comment: I believe another answer on the same question will work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query#answer-16332263

Comment: Andrew its two queries basically.. As i suggested.. buddy.

Comment: @Haroon yeah sorry about that, I pointed to the wrong answer, updated comment