# mysql query insert record in multiple table in single query at a time

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, mysql, oracle

How to insert data in different tables using MySql database?

like i want to insert cid=1,cname=sahil,bid=12345,amount=12000
customer 
cid,cname

bankb
bid,cid,amount

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Does not support multiple table data insert using single query,
however Oracle does it.

for MySQL you have to use multiple insert query

like

```
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(...)
INSERT INTO PHONES VALUES(...)
```

Source : [sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score -1):

Its not efficient with simple `query` and so use `Stored procedures`. Refer the below links.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/77ce4b34-581b-47c8-aad6-96910ecd8ab5/correct-way-to-insert-data-into-multiple-tables-stored-procedure?forum=sqlgetstarted