# Multiple INSERT query's fetching last_insert_id of each each

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO users(email, password) VALUES ('$email','$password')" );
$user_id = mysql_insert_id( );

mysql_query( "INSERT INTO business_details ( business_id, name, address, city, state, country, pincode) VALUES ('$category','$business_name', '$business_address', '$city', '$state', '$country', '$pincode')" );
$idB = mysql_insert_id( );

mysql_query( "INSERT INTO user_profiles (name, phone, user_id, business_details_id) VALUES ('$person_name', '$phone_number', '$user_id', '$idB')" );
```

What will be the best way to insert all queries in one? Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: If you want the last ids then run the queries separately.

Comment: How can i fetch last_insert_id of each, from your ref?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't supported in MySQL - only Oracle can do it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement