# Inserting one column each from two different tables to 2 column of a table

Tags: sql, codeigniter

This is may sample database

```
TABLE A-----> TABLE B <-----TABLE C
```

The arrows show the relationship

```
TABLE A 
{ 
   tblA_col1 <----primary key
} 
TABLE A
 (tblA_col1)
  | A_1  |<----data


TABLE C 
{ 
  tblC_col1 <----primary key
}
TABLE C
 (tblC_col1)
  | C_1  |<----data
  | C_2  |
  | C_3  |


TABLE B
{
  tblB_col1 <----primary key
  tblA_col1 <----col from table A
  tblC_col1 <----col from table C
}
TABLE B
(tblB_col1 |  tblA_col1  |  tblC_col1)
|   B_1    |     A_1     |    C_1    |
|   B_2    |     A_1     |    C_2    |
|   B_3    |     A_1     |    C_3    |
```

Now my problems is how to insert the data in `TABLE B` with just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into B (tblA_col1, tblC_col1 )
select A.tblA_col1, C.tblC_col1 from 
A, C;
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: yeah thanks, I tried it before but it didn't work..then i try it again it works!

Comment: Wow I thought It will not be possible. Never tried that though.But I think its fine and works.

Comment: yeah it work, and now my problem is how to convert it to insert data in Codeigniter

Comment: Well you know the query.So you can use `$this->db->query($query);`

Comment: got an error public function insert_req($s_no, $filed, $dat) 
        {
            $sql = "Insert into student_requirements (filed, datesubmitted, documents, r_no, s_no)"
                    . "($filed, $dat, (Select a.description, a.r_no, b.s_no from requirements a, student b where s_no = $s_no))";
            return $sql->result();

        } what can be done to this?

Comment: can i put select statement in insert into table B(col1, col2 col3) values (va1, val2, select statement)????

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this thread as the answer is related with your problem.

> MySQL doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement
>
> However, you CAN use a transaction and have both of them be contained within one transaction

[sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)