# How to insert to two tables with one query if one table is a junction table?

Tags: mysql

How can I INSERT values to two tables using only one query? I am using MySQL. One of the tables I want to insert to is a many-to-many relationship table. Please see my example below:

[image]

I recently added the many-to-many relationship tables. When I insert on the news, I type the following script:

```
INSERT INTO news (title, reporter_id) 
VALUES ('Some Title', 15);
```

How can I have one query an be able to insert to two tables? Per MySQL insert [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html), seems like I can do query like

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

The problem is, I dont know my news_id until I execute my first insert. Should I just have two insert statements or is there a better way? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO first; INSERT INTO SECOND(LAST_INSERT_ID()); END TRANSACTION;`

Comment: That syntax is for inserting multiple rows into a single table; not inserting into multiple tables. There is no syntax that I am aware of for doing that, aside from transactions, but those aren't really single queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: Also, what is the intended purpose of the `junctions` table? With the data shown, it looks redundant; but could be populated with an AFTER INSERT **trigger** on the `news` table.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks for correcting me! I am trying now

Comment: @Uueerdo Here is my complete query:

START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO news (title, reporter_id) VALUES ('Some Title', 22); INSERT INTO junctions (reporter_id, news_id) VALUES (22, LAST_INSERT_ID()); END TRANSACTION;

I get an error of error near near 'END TRANSACTION' at line 3. I tried several ways to debug. Do you know which error is it referring to? It seems to run the first insert transaction..

Comment: Use `COMMIT` instead of `END TRANSACTION`

Comment: Hi I just figured! Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Uueerdo in the comments, you can use an AFTER INSERT trigger and access the generated ID with `NEW.id`. However - if you want to keep that logic in your application layer, you can copy the data from the first table to the second after your bulk insert with:

```
start transaction;

insert into news(title, reporter_id) values
    ('title2', 2),
    ('title3', 3);

insert into junctions(news_id, reporter_id)
    select id, reporter_id
    from news
    where id >= last_insert_id()
    order by id asc
    limit 2;

commit;
```

This works for InnoDB if the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` is set to `0` or `1`, because the generated IDs are guaranteed to be consecutive.

> With `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` set to 0 (“traditional”) or 1 (“consecutive”), the auto-increment values generated by any given statement are consecutive, without gaps, because the table-level AUTO-INC lock is held until the end of the statement, and only one such statement can execute at a time.

[AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-mode-usage-implications)

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return the generated ID of the first inserted row.

> If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the value generated for the *first* inserted row *only*.

[Information Functions - LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

You know the first generated ID. You know the number of inserted rows. So you know which rows to copy.

Demo: http://rextester.com/UEN69961