# How to insert different values in different mysql tables with single query?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`f_name`, `l_name`, `mobile`) VALUES (firstname, lastname, 8877665544);
INSERT INTO `dept`(`deptname`, `usercount`) VALUES (deptnmae, 32);
```

how can I add both table values in single query at the same time in php mysql

Comment: It's not possible. You can only insert into one table at a time.

Comment: Use a transaction to make the two inserts atomic.

Comment: Inserting both at the same time doesn't create a sensible relationship between the two entries, btw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query) or [Insert into multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization).

Comment: You can do a transactional query but otherwise, you cannot insert it to two tables.