# Insert all in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Is there a way that we can replicate the functionality of 'Insert all' from oracle to mysql, where it is used to load the data(may be conditional at times) to multiple tables with same data at one shot.

Comment: Maybe this two topics will help: [MySQL Insert into multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178697/mysql-insert-into-multiple-tables-database-normalization) and [sql - insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/sql-insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: Thanks, for pointing it out , it confirms me there is no way to do, helps in interviews if asked.