# Insert data into 3 tables at once

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to `insert` values of data array in 3 tables. In one `insert` everything works fine, but in multiple inserts no. Also, is there any way to cancel the procedure if 1/3 table insert fails?

My code:

```
    if($_POST["action"] == 'Add')
{
    $data = array(
        ':afm'      =>  $_POST["afm"],
        ':fname'            =>  $visitor->clean_input($_POST["fname"]),
        ':lname'        =>  $visitor->clean_input($_POST["lname"]),
        ':city'     =>  $visitor->clean_input($_POST["city"]),
        ':street'       =>  $visitor->clean_input($_POST["street"]),
        ':company'      =>  $_POST["company"],
        ':email'        =>  $_POST["email"],
        ':phone'        =>  $_POST["phone"],
        ':make'     =>  $_POST["make"],
        ':model'        =>  $_POST["model"],
        ':gen'      =>  $_POST["gen"],
        ':engine'       =>  $_POST["engine"],
        ':plate'        =>  $_POST["plate"],
        ':vin'      =>  $_POST["vin"]
    );

    $visitor->query = "
    INSERT INTO Client 
    (afm, fname, lname, city, street, company, email) 
    VALUES (:afm, :fname, :lname, :city, :street, :company, :email)
        ";


    $visitor->query = "
    INSERT INTO Phone 
    (phone_type, phone, clientID) 
    VALUES ("main phone", :phone, :afm)
        ";


    $visitor->query = "
    INSERT INTO Vehicle 
    (plate, make, model, gen, engine, vin, clientID) 
    VALUES (:plate, :make, :model, :gen, :engine, :vin, :afm)
        ";

    $visitor->execute($data);

    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">success!</div>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. Use transactions. More post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860280/insert-into-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score 0):

## First insert

As you said, this work and I will assume here that you are correct.

## Second insert

This looks extremely suspect to me, your `" main phone"` looks to be syntactically incorrect. I doubt that this is your actual code. You will need to have a syntactically correct command there.

## Third insert

This looks to be syntactically correct.

## Overriding queries

Your second and the third query is assigned to `$visitor->query`. You will need to do

```
$visitor->query = ...
```

at the first assignment and

```
$visitor->query .= ...
```

in the second and the third. The reason is that first you are happy to initialize the `query` member, but on the second and the third command you would be unhappy if you would lose the earlier. Instead, you need to [append](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-append-a-string-in-php.php) the second and the third query.

## Transactions

This is how you can use a transaction:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt1->execute($query1);
$stmt2->execute($query2);
$stmt3->execute($query3);
$db->commit();
```

Also, it is recommended to break up your commands into 3 separate `exec` calls instead of merging them into a single one. If you want to execute all inside a single `execute`, then you need to call `->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1);`