# MySQL INSERT after JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I have two tables as shown below.

```
table1

site | Link type
-----+----------
 A   | pdf
 B   | html
 C   | NULL
 D   | NULL

Table2

site | link type
-----+----------
 C   | htm
 D   | doc
```

This is the result I want:

```
site | link type
-----+----------
 A   | pdf
 B   | html
 C   | htm
 D   | doc
```

I want an insert query to insert the values of link type from table 2 to table 1
where link type is null joined with the condition with of `table1.site = table2.site`.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO table1(linktype)
SELECT linktype FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.site=t2.site
```

I want a insert query. as update query is working and want to know how a insert can be done?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382842/mysql-insert-joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Completely edited after clarification:

Creation of table1:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `site` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linktype` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('A', 'pdf');
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('B', 'html');
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('C', null);
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('D', null);
```

Creation of table2:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table2`;
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `site` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linktype` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES ('C', 'htm');
INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES ('D', 'doc');
```

Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO 
    table1  
    (site, linktype)
    (
       SELECT 
           table2.site, 
           table2.linktype
       FROM 
           table2
       JOIN 
           table1
       ON 
           table1.site = table2.site
   )
;
```

Table1 after insert query:

[image: Table1]

Comment: I am using mysql so tried the second solution. It is not working. The value , htm and doc is getting added as new rows with null value in the site column. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can do it with update query:  " update table1 a join table2 b on  a.site=b.site set a.linktype=b.linktype where a.linktype is null"    ANyone can tell if insert is possible or not ?

Comment: So all you want to do is to make a copy of all linktypes in table1 that exists in table2?

Comment: See my edit. I have tested the code in my mysql-database and it gives the result as in your image.

Comment: Sorry still the same result. You have not added the condition that site column should match. Thanks.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27669228/table2.sql                           http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27669228/table1.sql   sql dump of two tables for testing

Comment: Alright, I'm giving up. You say you want to just move "htm" and "doc" from table2 to table1 BUT you also say they have to match when there aren't any matches since "htm" and "doc" doesn't exist in table1. If you can't give me good explanation of what you want to achieve then I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. The match should be for column name "site". Thanks for your help

Comment: I am afraid , I can not accept it. I need http://i.imgur.com/jAklc.png   You can try the update command I  have written in my second comment. I appreciate your help.My question is  whether the same can be done with "insert command"

Comment: Then the answer is no. Insert is only used for adding new rows. If you are going to get the same result you first need to delete to Ones that matches and then insert the new ones...

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I made an error in thinking that insert can be used with where clause. I accept you solution. More information about my problem can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query Thanks again