# How to retrieve data from multi-valued attributes in a relational database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Following is my database with 4 tables(Student, Course, Module, Instructor). And I wan to know whether this database is correct or not and if I am doing right how can I retrieve data from tables using student id as below.

- What are the modules student 10122342
  has?
  *>>Expected answer: **cn103, cn201***

[image]

```
(pk) = primary key and (fk)=foreign key
```

The next thing is I wan to import some values from those above tables to a newly created table? the situation is I wan to import 's_id' and 'i_id' from above tables in 'id' attribute of newly crated table named "Everyone"; at the same time I also want to generate '0'/'1' value for 'type' attribute of "Everyone" table where 0 value for those id which are imported from 's_id' and 1 for rest of the ids imported from 'i_id'. Following is my expected new database table.

```
Everyone
id       |type |
-----------------
10122345 | 0   |
10122342 | 0   |
10222346 | 0   |
20432343 | 1   |
20432311 | 1   |
20532334 | 1   |
```

Please Can anyone help me? is it possible to do with mysql and php? THanks.

Comment: why do you want to do the above? what if student and instructer ids overlap? seems like with this table structure, each student only gets to enroll in one course.

Comment: also, comma delimited values in a foriegn key is not good practice. how will you be able to use a join in a query to call this? if you ever have comma separated values in a table, it is a good sign that a separate table is needed.

Comment: consider having separate tables that join tables together. for instance having a table that just contains a student id and a course id which would represent which students are taking which courses. this way you can have each student take multiple courses and each course can be taken by multiple students.

Comment: Yes I understand that this is wrong. one student takes only one course and one course has multiple modules - here some of modules are on more than one course. This is the reason I am having trouble, I am expecting some kind of solution like String Compare or something to retrieve all the data. For now if i use the solution of @jeroen-offerijns from below Answer 1 it only shows one module that is assigned to only one course(cn103).

Answer (score 1):

This should be the answer to your first question:

```
SELECT m_code FROM Module a INNER JOIN Student b ON a.c_code = b.c_code WHERE b.s_id = '10122342'
```

I can't come up with the answer to your second question, though it should be something with joins, this might help: [MySQL Insert & Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382842/mysql-insert-joins)

Comment: it only gives 'cn103', it also suppose to retrieve 'cn201'??

Comment: What is the datatype of the c_code column in the Module table?