# SQL INSERT statement for TWO TABLES at time with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, insert, inner-join, mysql

I have two tables `hello` and `login_table` and below is their structure

```
user_info
-------
some_id | name | address

login_table
-------
id | username | password
```

`some_id` and `id` are autoincrement indexes.

Now how can i use `INSERT` statement with `INNER JOIN` in `SQL`

at present, i want add below data with same `some_id` and `id`

```
`name` = John
`address` = wall street
`username` = john123
`password` = passw123
```

below code shows, what i have tried so far.

```
insert into login_table lt
INNER JOIN user_info ui ON ui.some_id = lt.id
(ui.name, ui.address, lt.username, lt.password) 
values
('John', 'wall street', 'john123', 'passw123')
```

And this is not the one value, i want to add more than one value at a time.. how can i achieve.

thanks for help.

Comment: I don't think this is possible - you'll need two statements

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1382849/632951

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to perform the two `INSERT` operations atomically, use a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO login_table (username, password) VALUES ('john123', 'passw123');
INSERT INTO user_info (name, address) VALUES ('John', 'wall street');
COMMIT;
```

N.B. Your storage engine must support transactions for this to work (e.g. `InnoDB`).

To insert multiple values into a table at once, use the multiple rows form of `INSERT`.  As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html):

> [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) statements that use `VALUES` syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
> ```
>
> The values list for each row must be enclosed within parentheses. The following statement is illegal because the number of values in the list does not match the number of column names:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
> ```
>
> `VALUE` is a synonym for `VALUES` in this context. Neither implies anything about the number of values lists, and either may be used whether there is a single values list or multiple lists.

Comment: will also have same `id` ie.. in both table.. `id`'s are auto increment.. i tried and tested but its not working...

Comment: @Rafee in addition to the above, you can use the LAST_INSERT_ID() when you need to have the same id in both tables in case id was auto-generated. INSERT INTO foo (auto,text)
    VALUES(NULL,'text');
INSERT INTO bar (id,text)
    VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');

Comment: how to use Prepared Statement with this query ??

Answer (score 0):

Insert to two tables is impossible. The second part of your question is possible: you can insert multiple rows in one statement like this:

```
insert into some_table(col1, col2) values (1,2), (3,4), (5,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [ERPDb]
GO

INSERT INTO [AAA].[UserRole] ([UserId], [RoleId])
    SELECT u.Id, (SELECT Id FROM [AAA].[Role] WHERE Title = 'Employee') FROM [AAA].[User] u
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[BaseDealer] bd ON u.Id = bd.Id
    WHERE bd.DealerType = 0
GO
```