# MySql PHP Insert with join

Tags: php, mysql, join, insert

I can't get the following Insert to work although the syntax seems correct..

```
INSERT INTO views T
    JOIN members T2
        ON '$username' = T2.username 
(ITEM_ID, ITEM_TYPE, USER_ID, USER_TYPE) 
VALUES('$itemview', '$type', T2.id, '$usertype')
```

All the variables are predefined of course.. 
What am I doing wrong here?

The Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T JOIN members T2 ON 'testuser' = T2.username (ITEM_ID, IT' at line 1

Comment: How can you join two tables if the record hasn't been created yet?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382842/mysql-insert-joins) question's answer may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you want this syntax instead:

```
INSERT INTO views
  (ITEM_ID, ITEM_TYPE, USER_ID, USER_TYPE)
SELECT '$itemview', '$type', id, '$usertype'
FROM members
WHERE username = '$username'
```

It inserts a record into `views` with the partial contents of `members`. The number of rows returned with the `SELECT` also determines the number of inserted records; you may wish to use `LIMIT` if that's actually a problem.