# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wth JOIN for multiple rows insert in single query

Tags: mysql

I was studying this question:
  [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for multiple rows insert in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query)
 and this one:
 [MySQL Insert & Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382842/mysql-insert-joins)

And my question is an amalgamation of the two.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is `UPDATE` multiple rows with *different* values and I want to `JOIN` another table to check that the current logged user is allowed to `UPDATE` those rows.

If I understand correctly I can't do this with:

```
UPDATE beautiful 
JOIN employees on employees.id = beautiful.employee  
SET name='$name', age='$age'
WHERE employees.company = '$company'
```

because I can't plug in different values for each row.

I investigated using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, bearing in mind new rows will not be inserted, only existing rows will be updated.

```
INSERT INTO beautiful (employee,name, age)
      VALUES
      (1,'Helen', 24),
      (2,'Katrina', 21),
      (3,'Samia', 22),
      (4,'Hui Ling', 25),
      (5,'Yumie', 29) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       name= VALUES(name), age = VALUES(age)
```

The problem with this, again if I understand correctly, with `INSERT` I can only `JOIN` tables if I `INSERT` from a `SELECT` statement

but if I use a `SELECT` statement eg:

```
INSERT INTO beautiful (employee,name, age)
SELECT '1','Helen', '24'
FROM beautiful
JOIN employees on employees.id = beautiful.employee and employee.company = '$company'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
name= VALUES(name), age = VALUES(age)
```

I'm back to the problem of only being able to `UPDATE` a single row because I can't use more than one set of literal values in the `SELECT` statement.

How may I go about updating multiple rows with *different* values and joining each row on another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Union all:

```
INSERT INTO beautiful (employee,name, age)
SELECT * from 
FROM (
select '1','Helen', '24' 
union all
select '2','Katrina', '21' 
) beautiful
JOIN employees on employees.id = beautiful.employee and employee.company = '$company'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
name= VALUES(name), age = VALUES(age)
```

and you also can use PHP to make that union all syntax - eg: implode(' union all', $array_of_selects)

Comment: Thats brilliant, I cant remember how i solved the problem two years ago, but I'll bear this in mind going forward!